# Mapstruct avoid circular issue with List<A> property in B class

Tags: java, list, circular-dependency, relation, mapstruct

If I have a Class **ProfessorDto** and a Class **StudentDto** how can I avoid circular issues if the ProfessorDto have a list of StudentDto and the StudentDto have a property of type ProfessorDto ?
I didn't put the code of the domain class but let's say it is the same as for the Dto.

I'm new to Mapstruct, converting a domain bean to a Dto with simple properties like Long, String is working but in my exemple, the relation OneToMany is not working !

```
@JsonApiResource(type = "professor")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class ProfessorDto {

  @JsonApiId
  private Long id;

  private String professorName;

  @JsonApiRelation(mappedBy = "professor")
  private List<StudentDto> student;

  public ProfessorDto(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

And a class Student

```
@JsonApiResource(type = "student")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class StudentDto {

  @JsonApiId
  private Long id;

  private String studentName;

  @JsonApiRelation
  private ProfessorDto professor;
}
```

My Mapper for Professor is

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public interface ProfessorMapper {

  ProfessorDto domainToDto(Professor domain);

  Professor dtoToDomain(ProfessorDto dto);

  StudentDto studentToDto(Student student);

  Student studentDtoToDomain(StudentDto studentDto);

  List<StudentDto> studentToDto(List<Student> student);

  List<Student> studentDtoToDomain(List<StudentDto> studentDto);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check out this example using @Context annotation

https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/master/mapstruct-mapping-with-cycles/src/main/java/org/mapstruct/example/mapper

more about the @Context annotation can be found at the Mapstruct documentation below

https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/Context.html

Answer (score 0):

At first, you should decide if it is really needed to keep `List<StudentDto>` aggregated in `ProfessorDto`. You can just exclude it, if it's possible. 

 Otherwise, you can make either `StudentDto` or `ProfessorDto` 'flat'. For example, you can add field `Long professorId` instead of `ProfessorDto professor` to the `StudentDto`, or `List<Long> studentIds` to the `ProfessorDto`.

An sample approach using Mapstruct:

1. Change a DTO class like this:

   ```
   @JsonApiResource(type = "student")
   @NoArgsConstructor
   @Data
   public class StudentDto {

       @JsonApiId
       private Long id;

       private String studentName;

       private Long professorId; // <-- CHANGED 
   }
   ```
2. Add a Helper class, and provide custom mapping logic:

   ```
   @Component
   public class MapperHelper {
       @AfterMapping
       public void mapProfessorId(Student student, @MappingTarget StudentDto studentDto) {
           studentDto.setProfessorId(student.getProfessor().getId());
       }
   }
   ```